# Alpine custom tooltip directive darkmode with tippy.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js, tippyjs

I'm trying to implement the `tippy.js` tooltip and change the theme based on the local storage value `darkMode` as an `AlpineJs` [custom directive](https://alpinejs.dev/advanced/extending#custom-directives).

The code below works more or less fine with the latest bit that if I toggle the dark-mode switch, which changes the local localStorage item value of `darkMode`, I need a page refresh to get the new value.

How can I get the value (`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('darkMode'))`) while I change it?

#### app.js

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.directive('tooltip', (el, {expression, modifiers}) => {
        tippy(el, {
            content: expression,
            placement: modifiers[0] ?? 'auto',
            theme: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('darkMode')) ?'blue':'light-border'
        })
    })
})
```

#### tool-tip button

```html
<button type="button" x-tooltip.left="I'm a tooltip">Hover me</button>
```

#### darkmode

```html
<body class="font-sans antialiased h-full"
      x-data="{'darkMode': false}"
      x-init="
        darkMode = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('darkMode'));
        $watch('darkMode', value => localStorage.setItem('darkMode', JSON.stringify(value)))"
      x-cloak
>
<!-- some html -->
</body>
```

#### toggle button

```html
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox"  :value="darkMode" @change="darkMode = !darkMode"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see a Tippy.js instance and the `localStorage` is not reactive. After creating a Tippy.js instance we need to use the [`_tippy` property](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/tippy-instance/#-property) on each element if we want to change a property. To make it a little bit easier, I modified the tooltip directive to add a custom class `tooltips`, that we use to loop over each Tippy.js instance.

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.directive('tooltip', (el, { expression, modifiers }) => {
    tippy(el, {
      content: expression,
      placement: modifiers[0] ?? 'auto',
      theme: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('darkMode')) ? 'blue' : 'light-border'
    })
    el.classList.add('tooltips')
  })
})
```

And in the `$watch` magic, we use the `tooltips` class to find all of the Tippy.js instances and set the new theme on them.

```
<body class="font-sans antialiased h-full"
      x-data="{'darkMode': false}"
      x-init="
        darkMode = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('darkMode'));
        $watch('darkMode', value => {
            localStorage.setItem('darkMode', JSON.stringify(value))
            Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.tooltips')).forEach(
              el => el._tippy.setProps({ theme: value ? 'blue' : 'light-border' }))
        })"
      x-cloak
>
<!-- some html -->
</body>
```